# Mysql query returns no results when running from Node MySQL module

Tags: mysql, node.js

The query `SELECT * FROM products` return results when running from MySQL Workbench, but no results from Nodejs MySQL module:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'me',
  password: 'secret',
  database: 'products_database'
});

connection.connect(function(err){
  if(err) throw err;
});

connection.query('SELECT * FROM `products`', function(err, results, fields){
  console.log(results);
});

connection.end();
```

This returns no results.

Comment: Do `connection.end();` inside the callback, after `console.log(results);`

Comment: @Ananth It doesn't make any difference, still no results.

Comment: @Farzad , what is the result showing for the ``console.log(results);`` ?

Comment: @mmuzahid it's an empty array

Comment: @Farzad, May be its a very silly chance , re-write **\`products\`** as **products**

Comment: @mmuzahid That changed nothing too. But it return results with a query like `SHOW DATABASES`

Comment: @Farzad, cross check `database` name and `products` table is empty or not

Comment: @mmuzahid Both have content. I run the same query on the same database on Workbench and get results, and with no difference, it returns nothing on Node. It's also worth to mention that it doesn't return 'no results' (when `if(!results){console.log('no results')` is set), instead it returns an empty array, `[]`

Comment: Is there any value in `err`?

Comment: @bolav No, it's empty.

Comment: Your code runs without errors on my machine. Are you able to run `INSERT INTO` in node. Does the values enter the database?

Comment: @bolav It adds nothing to the database. It runs without any error but nothing is added.  To make sure about the query, I used `console.log(query.sql)` and pasted the result as Workbench input, and there, the query works fine and the values are added.

Comment: @bolav Maybe it's worth to note that although it doesn't add anything to the database, it affects the `id` column, which is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`. i.e. running `database.js` adds +1 to `id` value. For example, if the current `id` value is 20, after 5 times running `database.js` (which doesn't add anything to the database), and then using `INSERT INTO` in Workbench to add a new row, the `id` of the new row would be 25.

Comment: Check your database commit configuration

Comment: @mmuzahid Thank you! Changing the charset to "utf-8_bin" solved the issue. Before the change, the charset was set to "utf-8 defulat collation".

Comment: @Farzad I'm having a same error, I input `utf-8_bin` as a charset parameter in my connetion, but the error says that `Unknown charset 'utf-8_bin'`